# TFLiteConverter representative_dataset from keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I've got a dataset coming in via

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=validation_split,
  subset="training",
  seed=seed,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

(Based around code from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images with very minor changes to configuration)

I'm converting the eventual model to a TFLite model, which is working, but I think the model's too large for the end device so I'm trying to run post training quantization by supplying a `representative_dataset`  (like https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization)

However I can't work out how to turn the dataset generated from `image_dataset_from_directory` into the format expected by `representative_dataset`

The example provided has

```py
def representative_dataset():
  for data in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images)).batch(1).take(100):
    yield [data.astype(tf.float32)]
```

I've tried things like

```py
def representative_dataset():
  for data in train_ds.batch(1).take(100):
    yield [data.astype(tf.float32)]
```

but that wasn't it

Comment: Is there some error message being printed when you are running your code?

Comment: Lots of things like `'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'astype'` which suggests I'm not doing the `representative_dataset` in the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

```py
def representative_dataset():
  for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
    yield [image_batch]
```

Was what I was looking for, image_batch is already `tf.float32`

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` to work, but I had some luck with `tf.keras.preprocessing.ImageDataGenerator`.

In my case, the images were in the 'images/all' directory. I had to make sure to remove any non-image files (e.g. XML annotations) from that directory.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input

def representative_dataset():
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
  test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      './images', 
      target_size=(300, 300), 
      batch_size=1,
      classes=['all'],
      class_mode='categorical')
  for ind in range(len(test_generator.filenames)):
    img_with_label = test_generator.next()
    yield [np.array(img_with_label[0], dtype=np.float32, ndmin=2)]
```